# Include all objects but apply conditions only on associations in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

With the following models,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  # Has an attribute named active
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has an attribute named city
end
```

How do I fetch all `users` where `active: true` and for each user include only `addresses` where `city: Foo`, in a single query to the DB?

**Note:** If a user has no address where `city` is "Foo", they must still be included in the result with empty `addresses`.

### Example Data

```
test=# select * from users;
 id | name | active 
----+------+--------
  1 | Jack | t
  2 | John | t
  3 | Jane | t
  4 | Jill | f
(4 rows)

test=# select * from addresses;
 id | user_id |    street    | city 
----+---------+--------------+------
  1 |       1 | Foo Street   | Foo
  2 |       1 | Bar Street   | Bar
  3 |       2 | Bar Street   | Bar
  4 |       4 | Foo Street   | Foo
  5 |       1 | Foo Street 1 | Foo
(5 rows)
```

### Expected Result

```
 id | name |    street    | city 
----+------+--------------+------
  1 | Jack | Foo Street 1 | Foo
  1 | Jack | Foo Street   | Foo
  2 | John |              | 
  3 | Jane |              | 
(4 rows)
```

The below SQL query that can produce that result, but I can't figure out a way to get AR to generate that query or any other query to produce the above result.

```
select users.id, name, street, city from users left join lateral (
  select * from addresses where addresses.user_id = users.id and city = 'Foo'
) addr on true
where users.active;
```

Comment: Is this `User.includes(:addresses).where(active: true).where(addresses: {city: 'Foo'})` what you are looking for?

Comment: That excludes users who don't have any address in "Foo".

Comment: Your request is not very clear, as evidenced by the various answers that don't produce what you are trying to get. Consider presenting examples of a few User records with various combinations of Addresses and show the desired filtered result.

Comment: Added some examples.

Answer (score 0):

please try
add in `Address` model

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
end
```

then your query be like

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN addresses ON users.id=addresses.user_id").where("users.active=? AND addresses.city=?", true, "FOO")
```

Comment: Nope, that's not what want. It excludes users that don't have any `address` where `city: Foo` and needs separate queries to fetch the attributes of matching addresses.

Comment: try `Inner Join`User.joins(:addresses)

Comment: That'll exclude users who don't have any address at all, but really changes nothing. :)

Comment: :)
try .where("users.active=? AND addresses.city=?", true, "FOO")

Comment: How is this different from Pavan's suggestion in his direct comment on the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`User.joins("LEFT JOIN addresses on addresses.user_id = users.id").where(active: true).select("users.*,if (addresses.city = 'Foo', addresses.city, '') AS 'city',if (addresses.city = 'Foo', addresses.street, '') AS 'street'").order("city").group(:id).uniq(:id)`

Comment: This excludes users who have addresses with cities other than "Foo".

Comment: So why  you want to filter with `Foo` if you need all records you can use `group_by`  to group result with city `Foo`  and with city `orther`

Comment: I have updated the question with example data and result. Hopefully that clarifies things.

Comment: That returns `User` objects without any address first and when I try to access the `addresses` attribute, it fires a query for each user and includes all addresses without applying the city condition.

Comment: you don't need to access the `addresses` by `user.addresses`.The `address` is already `join` to the `user` table. You can directly access `user.city` or `user.street`

Comment: Uniq on `User.id` is not what I want. A `User` can have multiple addresses in the same city. Without that, this returns duplicate users.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it can be achieved in this way , i hope it might be correct :-

```
User.all.select{|a|a.active == true}.map(&:address).flatten.select{|v|v.city == "Foo" || v.city == ""}
```

Think it can be modified to get the proper result . Hope it helps and please do correct me if i am gone wrong .